# How does mechanics works behind "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve..." errors

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ngx-editor

I'd like to understand why this is failing, because as far as I know it shouldn't.

As soon as I include the following line in my code

```
import { NgxEditorComponent } from 'ngx-editor/app/ngx-editor/ngx-editor.component';
...
@ViewChild('editor') editor: NgxEditorComponent;
```

the following error shows up:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-editor/app/ngx-editor/ngx-editor.component

And it doesn't make sense to me, since the component (although a little bit bugged) seems to work alright. Even if I change the type declaration for "any", I can do a

```
console.log(editor);
```

without issue, and the browser's console returns

> NgxEditorComponent {_messageService: MessageService, _commandExecutor: CommandExecutorService, _renderer: DebugRenderer2, resizer: "stack", config: {…}, …}

In addition to that, VSCode intellisense locates the module right away, and I can confirm that it is under node_modules folder.

I'd like to clarify that I'm not looking for a workaround for this issue, but to gain a better understanding of the underlying mechanisms involved.

Thank you in advance

Comment: When are you getting this error? At run time? Or compile time?

Comment: Compile time. Just as I save. ng serve is sunning

Comment: to which module this component belong?is the path to file correct?

Comment: It's ngx-editor, vertika. The path is correct, or at leat VSCode thinks it is. It's under node-modules, and when I click on it I get proprerly redirected to the file. It looks like it's the compiler working for `ng serve` is failing for some reason, but only when I specifically declare it's type.

Comment: have you imported the module in your main module file .. ?

Comment: Yup. The module is working for all purposes, but I just can't declare the type of it's components in the code

Comment: hey ! your problem got solved ? I ran into the same issue . and i found that it is because of the path. I was giving :
// import { WalkthroughModule } from 'src/lib/ngx-walkthrough-master/ngx-walkthrough-master/src/modules/walkthrough.module';
which gave me an error.

Comment: then i gave import {WalkthroughModule} from '../../lib/ngx-walkthrough-master/ngx-walkthrough-master/src/modules/walkthrough.module'; which solved my error.